# Decorating class methods to call a method from the same name

Tags: python, oop, python-decorators

I have a class with a bunch of similar-looking methods, as such:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, delegate= None):
        self.delegate = delegate
    
    def some_method(self):
        if self.delegate:
            return self.delegate.some_method()

        return "this is some other value"
```

My idea  was a wrapper like:

```
def use_delegate(fun):
    def wrap(self, *args):
        if self.delegate:
             return fun(self.delegate, *args)
        return fun(self, *args)

    return wrap

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, delegate= None):
        self.delegate = delegate

    @use_delegate
    def some_method(self):
        return "this is some other value"
```

Here's the problem: if "self.delegate" is a subclass of Foo, the wrong method is invoked:

```
    class Bar(Foo):
        def some_method(self):
            return "This is the output I want"

    >>> bar = Bar()
    >>> bar.some_method()
 'This is the output I want'
    >>> foo= Foo(bar)
    >>> foo.some_method()
 'this is some other value'
```

So far I've found this works, but it looks really ugly:

```
def use_delegate(fun):
    def w(self, *args):
        if self.delegate:
            return self.delegate.__getattribute__(fun.__name__)(*args)

        return fun(self, *args)

    return w
```

I wonder if there's a nicer way to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Why wrap the instance `delegate` instead of using it directly? This looks like a design problem.

Comment: Indeed I suspect my design is terrible, I'll have to think it over, but still I think it makes for a nice programming puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I have tried your (original)decorator without Bar being a subclass of Foo and it didn't work for me. Which is logical because, in your first wrapper you call `fun`, which is the function `some_method` of Foo. You can see it in the debugger:

```
function Foo.some_method at 0x...
```

I'm actually a little surprised it works, but then again it's python(you can even replace self.delegate with a string or an int or wathever and it will still work).

Now onto the next decorator way. I think what you have written hasn't a nicer solution if you want to keep the decorator. So, the only small improvements that I could find are:

```
def use_delegate(fun):
    def w(self, *args):
        if self.delegate:
            assert hasattr(self.delegate, fun.__name__) # here
            return getattr(self.delegate, fun.__name__)(*args) # and here

        return fun(self, *args)

    return w
```

Comment: At this point it's just curiosity, but how would you address the problem in a different way than decorators?

Comment: I would do it like you first did. `return self.delegate.some_func if self.delegate else "..."` . Anything else seems to far fetched. But as chepner has said, it looks like a design problem.